# Android TabWidget text margin/padding

Tags: android, android-tabs

The margin/padding is taking too much place in the app.
Currently the layout height is:64dp.
And I want it to be about:32dp.
The problem is, when I change the height to 32dp, the text in the tab-widget is cut because of the content inside of it.
What should I do in order of making the height 32dp, without hiding parts of the tab headers.

Comment: I'm not understanding "the text in the tab-widget is cut because of the content inside of it".  Maybe post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the tab header text is getting cut off, this should fix it:

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
```

That gives you a tab header that looks like this:

[image: text tab image]